# How to say "Take it or leave it"?

Tags: professionalism, resume, conversation

I am a freelancer and recently one of my clients was pinging me day and night about a particular project. He dug out EVERY little detail of the project and pinged me a lot of times whether I could handle something like that or not.

> So is there any polite way to close the conversation or to just simply convey the message-'Take it or leave it?' without offending the client?

**P.S.** I can only *hope* he doesn't see this message.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to quit support or do you want to organize your work and get paid?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That is the reason why I posted this question- to find a politer way of conveying the same thing

Comment: your question contains a or. Thich do you want, close the conversation?
And by take it or leave it, whats the it you are refering to? Did you make an offer? Is the project already start, do you want it to start?

Comment: It’s not clear what you want. *find a politer way of conveying the same thing* Which thing? Benjamin’s first comment asked about two options but you never said which one you wanted.

Comment: The most simple advice is to document the times the client called you and the amout of time it took to process the request. Then you send them an invoice. They can decide whether they pay and continue. They can also stop calling because they understand you do not do the work for free.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler So you suggest "Pay it or Leave it". Good one, should be an answer.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I did not want to post it as an answer as I had no idea if this is a direction the asker is willing to take.

Comment: "Take it or leave it" means to agree to something as-is. Are you suggesting that  the client is asking for extra? If so, I think the usual answer is "that will cost extra." If the client is just asking for clarification, then that would suggest that your proposal skills were lacking and you should probably just continue answering their questions. If the project is complete and you would like to deliver as-is, then you can politely say "I'm sorry, I have completed the project per the specifications and am unable to provide additional support at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

*Dear name of client, I have now completed what we agreed in the initial contact, I can justify to spend a few more hours on this project as part of the original delivery, but soon we reach a point where I must charge my hourly rate to comply with your change requests.*

Comment: Where does OP say that they completed a project? This also doesn't make sense in regards to the "Take it or leave it," which sounds more like it's talking about a proposal--a project that has not even started yet

Comment: True - it doesn't say if this is in the pre sale or after completion phase, my suggestion is relevant when the project is completed but the client expected a Ferrari at a Fiat price point.

Comment: If you completed a project, "leave it" would suggest that they don't pay you, so that doesn't sound like a likely situation...

Comment: Then hopefully there will be a more relevant answer soon. This one we leave here if some future reader have finds some inspiration in it ;-)